# Laptop doesn't detect the wireless connection

Tags: windows-7, windows, wireless-networking, windows-8, wireless-access-point

There are 2 access points in the area. 2 laptops -one of them has Windows 7 and the other has Windows 8- detect only one of them which is farther. Other computers in the area can detect and connect both of them. I've reinstalled the drivers, but it didn't fix it.

Comment: Are these your WAP's or do they require passwords for access?

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you sure that your wireless is on?
2. Are you sure that your Air plan mode is off?
   Check these in your PC Setting.go to charm bar in the right screen.click on settings and then in bottom of all options click on "change PC setting". Now go to wireless setting from the left panel and check your PC's config.